# Start service from an activity in a new thread and let it runs independently?

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-activity

I appreciate any advice about what can I do, because I was searching for an example or a clear explanation and I could not find.

Actually I think that I have to separate problems:

1- I want to start a service from an activity, this service should run in the background in a new thread and keep on running all the time even if I close the activity interface, even if the mobile is not active...

2- Once I open again the activity (by clicking on the application icon), I want that Activity indicate for me that the service is running and I can stop it if I want or I can keep it running and close the activity interface again.

Any relevant tutorials, links or codes are welcome :-)

Thank you, R.

Answer (score 0):

is the Asynk Task not able to do this?? Have you tried it?? Like Java we have a special kind of thread or service in android which does its work in background without affecting your UI means you will not get any ANR(Application Not Responding Errors).

Comment: Thank you Narendra, I will check it more in details. R.